# get value of selected dropdown option in yii2 controller

Tags: yii2, yii-form

I'm trying to get value of selected dropdown menu from signup form. i need to store that value in db. 
dropdown code is.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'sex')->dropDownList(['1' => 'Male', '2' => 'Female'],['prompt'=>'Select Gender...'] )?>
```

I have tried with property 'sex[]' here. but it didn't help.

i have tried in controller with post request.

```
 $post=Yii::$app->request->post();
    $chosen = Yii::$app->request->post('sex', '');

    print_r($chosen);
    print_r($post->sex);

    echo "1:".$this->sex;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "2:".$this->sex;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "3:".$this->sex[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "4:".$this->sex[1];
    echo "<br>";
```

but non of these printed the vlaue in post submitted.
it contains the value for sex. here is the print_r($post) result
[sex]=>1 but if is use'sex[]'in dropdown it shows something like [sex]=>array( [0]=>1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to select more than one, make sure that you create it as array in form Property
**sex[]**

like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'sex[]')->dropDownList(['1' => 'Male', '2' => 'Female'],['prompt'=>'Select Gender...'] )?>
```

then load it to your model

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
```

it would be

`$model->sex` (that is an array).

**if you want to select just one option**

you have to had something like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'sex')->.... ?>
```

and your answer will be $model->sex (that is 1 or 2)

Comment: Thank you man @yafater you helped me with a hint. finally i found my solution because of you. please accept and add edited answer.